# how does rust compiler handle manufacturer specified instructions for riscv?

Tags: rust, riscv

As we know, riscv allow any manufacturer to add their custom instructions for their products, this is especially common in embedded cpu. And also, the manufacturers often provides the user with their modified version of GCC to compile code for there chips.

But how about the rust compiler? It seems that seldom of manufacturer will provide a modified rust compiler for there chips.

Will this be a huge disadvantage for rust when use rust in embedded or low level kernel programming? And how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons llvm was invented, instead of having to implement a compiler for every language-architecture pair one has only to implement one frontend for every language and one backend for every architecture, I expect manufactures more and more to shift from providing a custom gcc to provide a custom llvm backend at which point rust will support that target since it builds upon llvm.